# How do I download my whole repository from GitLab?

Tags: git, clone, gitlab

I can't work out how to download my entire repository for a given project.  Most of the things I do seem to just download the latest snapshot, e.g.

```
git pull https://gitlab.com/blahblah/MyProject.git
```

The reason I want to know how to do this is for "recovery" purposes: accidental deletion, if my PC blew up, got stolen, etc.

There doesn't seem to be a "forum" as such for GitLab, hence my posting here.

Comment: Every clone *is* the repository (or some subset of branches). That's the point of DVCSes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, it is missing lost branches etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I can't work out how to download my entire repository for a given project.

Use `git clone`.

> This procedure assumes you have already created a repository on
>   GitHub, or have an existing repository owned by someone else you'd
>   like to contribute to.
>
> - On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
> - Under the repository name, click Clone or download.
>
>   [image]
> - In the Clone with HTTPs section, click to copy the clone URL for the repository.
>
>   [image]
> - Open Git Bash.
> - Change the current working directory to the location where you want the cloned directory to be made.
> - Type `git clone`, and then paste the URL you copied in Step 2.
>
>   ```
>   git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
>   ```
> - Press Enter. Your local clone will be created.
>
>   ```
>   git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
>   Cloning into `Spoon-Knife`...
>   remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
>   remove: Total 10 (delta 1), reused 10 (delta 1)
>   Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
>   ```

Source [Cloning a repository - User Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)

Comment: Thanks... actually I had already found that page and tried that command... I should have clarified the problem: I found that the result of `clone` does indeed include a .git subdirectory... but the objects/ directory under it is only 650 kB... whereas the objects/ directory under the .git subdirectory in the local repository is 2.58 MB.  I had wrongly (I presume) assumed that this meant it wasn't a true/complete clone. What I really need is an explanation of this volume difference...

Comment: OP asks for gitlab, no github, but it is essentially the same.